# How to only autofit row height if cell is the largest?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of rows that base on two columns "A" & "I" that on worksheet event change, will autofit the row. My code works fine on one row/column, but when the other row/column is smaller than the previous, the initial row/column height gets shrink with the last row/column. I need help with if on worksheet event change, if the max height is already there to not autofit.

```
Sub AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight(Target As String)
    Dim MergeWidth As Single
    Dim cM As Range
    Dim AutoFitRng As Range
    Dim CWidth As Double
    Dim NewRowHt As Double
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set AutoFitRng = Range(Target)

    With AutoFitRng
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="410"
        .MergeCells = False
        CWidth = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
        MergeWidth = 0
        For Each cM In AutoFitRng
            cM.WrapText = True
            MergeWidth = cM.ColumnWidth + MergeWidth
        Next
        'small adjustment to temporary width
        MergeWidth = MergeWidth + AutoFitRng.Cells.Count * 0.66
        .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergeWidth
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        NewRowHt = .RowHeight
        .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = CWidth
        .MergeCells = True
        .RowHeight = NewRowHt
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="410"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 12 To 417
        If Target.Address = "$A$" & i Then
            Call AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight(Target.MergeArea.Address)
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$I$" & i Then
            Call AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight(Target.MergeArea.Address)
        End If
    Next i
```